# Unable to create data through show method in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am working on notifications I have 2 tables: one is `notify` and the other is `notify_status`. Through notify I am showing data like `title` and `description` and in `notify_status` I have field `read_status` which is by default `0`. After I show it I want to change it to `1`. I also have `notify_id` in it as a foreign key. This is my `show` method:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $notify        = Notify::find($id);
    $notify_status = NotifyStatus::where('notify_id', $id)->get();

    $user_data['read_status'] = 1;
    $user = NotifyStatus::create($user_data);

    return view('notify.desr')->with(compact('notify'));
}
```

But it isn't creating against `notify_id`. What should I do?

Comment: You don't want to create, you want to update it! `$notify_status->update(['read_status' => 1]);` - Otherwise this makes no sense.

Comment: it says method update not exist

Comment: Yeah, right - it also should be `NotifyStatus::where('notify_id', $id)->first();`, because `get()` returns a Collection and not the model. Also, if you have linked your models with relationships, the whole method should be one line of code: `$notify = Notify::find($id)->notify_status->update(['read_status' => 1]);` (I assume you have a 1:1 relationship between Notify and NotifyStatus and the relationship on the Notify-model is called 'notify_status').

Answer (score 0):

Your models should define the following relationships:

```
class Notify extends Model
{
    public function setAsRead()
    {
        $this->status->read_status = 1
        $this->status->save();
    }

    public function wasRead()
    {
        return (bool) $this->status->read_status;
    }

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(NotifyStatus::class);
    }
}

class NotifyStatus extends Model
{
    public function notify()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Notify::class);
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Laravel Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) for further reading.

In your controller you can use it like:

```
$notify = Notify::find($id);

$notify->status->read_status = 1;
$notify->status->save();

return view('notify.desr')->with(compact('notify'));
```

Or you can simply create a new method to set the new status (take a look at first method of Notify class):

```
$notify = Notify::find($id);

$notify->setAsRead();

return view('notify.desr')->with(compact('notify'));
```

Comment: what is status in 2nd method

Comment: in 2nd method it says save not exist

Answer (score 0):

```
public function show($id)
{
    $notify        = Notify::find($id);
    $notify_status = NotifyStatus::where('notify_id', $id)->first();

    $notify_status->read_status = 1;
    $notify_status->save()

    return view('notify.desr')->with(compact('notify'));
}
```